# Does Textbox.Text.GetTypeCode() always return "string"?

Tags: c#

Just wondering if the value in the text box was an int, would GetTypeCode return int or string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Textbox.Text is a String object, therefore it will always returning the TypeCode of a String object ("string" in this case).

Check out [String.GetTypeCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.gettypecode.aspx) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

The value of the `Text` property of the textbox is always a `string`, doesn't matter if you put a number in there, so it'll always return that it's a string.

Answer (score 0):

Justin is right.

You would have to to a Int32.TryParse to test if the value can be an int.